# Firebird database and Laravel

Tags: laravel, firebird

I need to setup a database using firebird and access to its data using laravel. I already have a simple database with a single column (user) but i dont even know how to "put it online" or setup a server to make the database accessible. 
I never worked it Firebird before and im kinda confused. It's a new concept for me, as I only worked with Xampp and PhpMyAdmin, which I'm confortable with.
How do I get the "Host" and stuff of a firebird database?
How can I access to it?
Any help is apreciated!

Table of users:

```
    CREATE TABLE "USER" (
    ID          INTEGER NOT NULL,
    NAME        VARCHAR(30),
    EMAIL       VARCHAR(40),
    PASSWORD    VARCHAR(100)
);

ALTER TABLE "USER" ADD CONSTRAINT PK_USER PRIMARY KEY (ID);
```

Comment: We need more specifics about your production and development systems to be able to help. Where do your db instances live? Is your Firebird instance local to the box with your laravel web app? Please provide more detail about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @JeremyAnderson Well, not much I can tell, because there isn't much more that i know about xD (I know, im dumb...) 
Well, right know, the db file (TEST.FDB) lives in my C: drive and I want Laravel separeted from where the db will be...

What i really want to achieve is to have a DB to hold the data, Laravel as backend and Angular as frontend.. 

Like : DB < ---- > Laravel < ----- > Angular. 
Hope it helps

Comment: Install Firebird server, and specify the server name of the machine hosting Firebird in the laravel connection configuration? Your question is very vague as to what you are really asking.

Comment: "I never worked it Firebird before " -  http://www.firebirdfaq.org/cat1/ and https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/qsg25.html

Comment: You may want to consider checking the chapter on PHP in the new [Firebird 3 Developers Guide](https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/#fbdevgd30), it includes an example on Laravel. Hopefully that will be helpful for you.